# Count number of strike-through lines

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a cell having multiple lines of data. Some of these lines are strike-through.

Now, I want to know that how many number of lines inside that cell are strike-through.

So, how to do that through some formula or VBA?

All the lines are either fully strike-through or not. Nothing partial.

By line, we mean number of lines as separated by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside a cell.

Comment: You will need to iterate the characters, when you find a line break test if the next character is strike through and count.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you already have tried something please edit your question to show this, so that we can help find the errors. Otherwise this question might be closed.

Comment: What kind of strike-through lines? Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling like doing a bit of free coding services today....

Can use in a cell as `=CountStrikeThrough(A2)` or in VBA as `Debug.Print CountStrikeThrough(Sheet1.Range("A2"))`

```
Public Function CountStrikeThrough(Target As Range) As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim bStrikeInRow As Boolean
    
    For x = 1 To Len(Target)
        With Target.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1)
            
            'If new row character found then reset strike-throughs found in row to false.
            If .Text = vbLf Then bStrikeInRow = False
            
            'If character is a strike-through and no strike-throughs found in row yet
            'add one to the count and change boolean to strike-throughs found in this row (true).
            If .Font.Strikethrough And Not bStrikeInRow Then
                bStrikeInRow = True
                lCount = lCount + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next x
    
    CountStrikeThrough = lCount
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It had been a long time and finally here is a solution :-)